# Laravel exception A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: exception, laravel-5, php-7.1

I'm getting an exception "A non-numeric value encountered" on the line where there's a code something like this

```
$data = $d->events()->where('event_type', 'something')->count();
```

I had this thing working OK with PHP 7.0 & Laravel one version point down, but upgrading to PHP 7.1 and laravel to latest, I started getting this exception

I tried to remove the count() and dd the result, but no luck

I've now Laravel - 5.4.15 (may be latest)

Comment: So what do you get from a dd on the above?

Comment: It's tell you that what you are getting back from your database query result.   If result is null then it can't be count.